# Find a 3rd order linear homogeneous differential equation with constant coefficients whose solution is $y=x\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find a 3rd order linear homogeneous differential equation with constant coefficients whose solution is $y=x\sin(x)$

---

Here is my attemot so far
$$y = x\sin x\\y'=x\cos x+\sin x\\y'' = -x\sin x + 2\cos x\\y''' = -x\cos x - 3\sin x$$

I am stuck here. Any help ?

Comment: I think i need to take linear combinations of derivatives in a specific way so that they add up to 0. I am not able eyeball the perfect combination :O

Comment: This is what you have to do. Group the terms.

Comment: Yes how should I find the constants A,B,C,D that yield $$Ay''' + By'' + Cy'+Dy = 0$$

Comment: Replace the derivatives by your expressions and group together $\sin(x)$, $x\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)$, $x\cos(x)$ and say that the coefficients are all zero. This will give you four equations. But remove $D$; then $3$ equations probably.

Comment: $$A(-x\cos x - 3\sin x) + B(-x\sin x + 2\cos x) + C(x\cos x + \sin x) + D(x\sin x) = 0$$  like this ?

Comment: Expand and group the terms which are the same.

Comment: The problem has no solution.

Comment: I am trying on my notes one sec

Comment: $$\sin x(-3A+C) + \cos x(2B) + x\sin x(-B+D) + x\cos x(-A+C) = 0$$

Comment: Are sinx, cosx, xsinx, xcosx are independent ? Is that the reason equating the constants to 0 works ?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter. You are perfectly right ! I missed it. Thanks for pointing my stupidity. Cheers :)

Comment: Oh does that mean there is no 3rd order eqn whose solution is xsinx ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have computed $y$, $y'$, $y''$, and $y'''$ for the given function $y(x):=x\sin x$. The first thing to try is to introduce undetermined coefficients $a_0$,$a_1$,$a_2$, $a_3$, and to check whether it is possible to attain
$$a_0y(x)+a_1y'(x)+a_2y''(x)+a_3y'''(x)\equiv0$$
with a suitable choice of the $a_k$. Now the $y^{(k)}$ contain terms of the form $\cos x$, $\sin x$, $x\cos x$, $x\sin x$, so that we will obtain a system of four linear equations in the four unknowns $a_k$. If this system has a  nontrivial solution $(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3)$ we can  present
$$a_0y+a_1y'+a_2y''+a_3y'''=0$$
as a solution to the given problem. Doing the calculations you'll find out that the only solution is the trivial one: $a_0=a_1=a_2=a_3=0$. This means that there is **no** third-order linear homogeneous ODE having $x\mapsto x\sin x$ as solution.

This has a reason: The solution space of a linear homogeneous ODE is translation invariant. Therefore, if $x\mapsto \sin x$ is a solution of such an ODE then so is  $x\mapsto\cos x$, and as a consequence the functions $x\mapsto e^{ix}$ and $x\mapsto e^{-ix}$ both are solutions of this ODE. Therefore both $i$ and $-i$ are roots of the characteristic polynomial associated to this ODE. Similarly: If $x\mapsto x\sin x$ is a solution of such an ODE then necessarily both $i$ and $-i$ have to be at least double roots of the characteristic polynomial. The simplest polynomial (even allowing complex coefficients) of this kind is
$$p(\lambda):=(\lambda-i)^2(\lambda+i)^2=\lambda^4+2\lambda^2+1\ .$$
It follows that the simplest linear homogeneous ODE having $x\mapsto x\sin x$ as a solution is
$$y^{(4)}+2y''+y=0\ .$$

Comment: Thank you so much :) If it is not complicated, may I know why $i$ and $-i$ have to be roots of characteristic polynomial 
?

Comment: @pooja: See my edit.